# How to say “multinational corporation”?

Tags: vocabulaire

Is there any word in French for “multinational corporation” which refers to a huge enterprise that has a global presence?

Comment: Pour ce genre de problème utilisez http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=multinational+corporation

Comment: Have you tried looking in dictionaries? Several online dictionaries have entries, including [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/multinational%20corporation) and [Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/multinational%20corporation). Linguee was already mentioned, and for words or short phrases, [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/multinational%20corporation) is pretty good. If you have looked and still have problems, please mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Just say "une multinationale" or "une entreprise multinationale"